# Javascript regular expression between brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

Let's say in the following text

```
I want [this]. I want [this too]. I don't want \[this]
```

I want the contents of anything between `[]` but not `\[]`. How would I go about doing that? So far I've got `/\[([^\]]+)\]/gi`. but it matched everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one: `/(?:^|[^\\])\[(.*?)\]/gi`

Here's a working example: http://regexr.com/3clja

- `?:` Non-capturing group
- `^|[^\\]` Beggining of string or anything but `\`
- `\[(.*?)\]` Match anything between `[]`

Here's a snippet:

```js
var string = "[this i want]I want [this]. I want [this too]. I don't want \\[no]";
var regex = /(?:^|[^\\])\[(.*?)\]/gi;
var match = null;

document.write(string + "<br/><br/><b>Matches</b>:<br/> ");
while(match = regex.exec(string)){
   document.write(match[1] + "<br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regexp, which first matches the `\[]` version (but doesn't capture it, thereby "throwing it away"), then the `[]` cases, capturing what's inside:

```
var r = /\\\[.*?\]|\[(.*?)\]/g;
         ^^^^^^^^^                  MATCH \[this]
                   ^^^^^^^^^        MATCH [this]
```

Loop with `exec` to get all the matches:

```
while(match = r.exec(str)){
  console.log(match[1]); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`/(?:[^\\]|^)\[([^\]]*)/g`

The content is in the first capture group, $1

`(?:^|[^\\])` matches the beginning of a line or anything that's not a slash, non-capturing.

`\[` matches a open bracket.

`([^\]]*)` captures any number of consecutive characters that are not closed brackets

`\]` matches a closing bracket

Comment: This doesn't match [something at the beggining]